# Max value of input from selected data-attribute

Tags: jquery

i'm setting max value of an input based on the selection.

if any of the option is selected i want its `data-max` attribute, to be set as max in the input field.

**The select options**

```
<select size="1" name="options" class="select">
  <option value="30" data-max="40">30</option>
  <option value="31" data-max="22">31</option>
  <option value="32" data-max="4">32</option>
  <option value="33" data-max="400">33</option>
  <option value="34" data-max="36">34</option>
</select>
```

**this is the input where max value will be set:**

```
<input type="number" class="qty" name="qty" value="1" min="1" max="100" />
```

**Tried this, but didn't worked**

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(this).data('max'));
});
```

**[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kzdaLa1/4/)**

Comment: Why don't you put the max in the `value`, instead of using a separate `data-max` attribute?

Comment: @Barmar because there isn't an easy way available so i'm doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use the data-max instead of the value itself but if this is really what you want to do, you need to get the option element first in order to use it's data-max value.  (Currently, you are using the data-max of the input).

```
$('select').change(function (e) {
    var selectedIndex = $('select').prop("selectedIndex");
    var selectedOption = $('select').find("option")[selectedIndex];
    $('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(selectedOption).data('max'));
});
```

Comment: thank you, your answer works :)
PS: i can't set the max-value in HTML easily, so i'm doing it that way

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the data attribute of the chosen option, not the select element.

Change:

```
$('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(this).data('max'));
```

to:

```
$('input[type=number]').attr('max', $('option:selected',this).data('max'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2kzdaLa1/7/)**

Comment: I prefer your answer to mine :)